# Small single parquet file on Data Lake, or relational SQL DB?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, bigdata, parquet, azure-data-lake

I am designing a Data Lake in Azure Synapse and, in my model, there is a table that will store a small amount of data (like 5000 rows).

The single parquet file that stores this data will surely be smaller than the smallest recommended size for a parquet file (128 MB) and I know that Spark is not optimized to handle small files. This table will be linked to a delta table, and I will insert/update new data by using the MERGE command.

In this scenario, regarding performance, is it better to stick with a delta table, or should I create a SQL relational table in another DB and store this data there?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on multiple factors like the types of query you will be running and how often you want to run merge command to upsert data to delta.
But even if you do perform analytical queries, looking at the size of data I would have gone with relational DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will be updating both small and large delta tables 3 times a day at first, but eventually 24 times a day (once per hour). 

I will run queries from Power BI, so ingestion of this small tables will be run probably a few times a day